# Is it possible to deserialize a Field to a Property?

Tags: c#, deserialization

I want to change a Field to a Property, but this results in problems with deserializing.

Is it somehow possible to deserialize from a Field to a Property?

After changing the from a Field to Property the deserialzed value is null instead.

```
// Old Class
public class myClass
{
    public string limits = "";
}

// New Class
public class myClass
{
    public string limits { get; set; } = "";
}

// Code for deserializing byte array (arrBytes)
using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
{
     var binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
     memStream.Write(arrBytes, 0, arrBytes.Length);
     memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
     var obj = binForm.Deserialize(memStream);
     return obj;
}
```

Is there any way to support the change from a Field to a Property?

Comment: This would require some form of [custom serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/serialization/custom-serialization).

Comment: The fact that you require this means you're using `BinaryFormatter` to do the wrong thing. `BinaryFormatter` is suitable for one thing only, and that is transport of objects between different parts of your program, usually between AppDomains. The needs you have now usually stems from using `BinaryFormatter` for storage, which is almost certainly going to cause you lots of grief over time. My advice would be to move away from `BinaryFormatter` completely and use one of the many alternatives more suited for long-term storage, where changes like this can occur.

Answer (score 0):

You could leave the serialization as-is, and wrap a property round the field.

```
public class myClass
{
    public string limits = "";

    public string Limits {
        get { return limits; }
        set { limits = value; }
    }

}
```